# Intent back to previous activity crashing

Tags: android, android-intent

caused by a string object is reading as null which is initialized.

```
    public String lastAction = "";
```

in `onCreate`

```
lastAction = model.lastAction;
```

it's working perfectly on the first `onCreate`, but when we go to the second activity and that `lastAction` object is `null` when back to previous activity using intent.

Comment: Not clear *when we go to second activity and that "lastAction" object is null when back to previous activity using intent.*

Comment: class A contains an string object, i move to class B and back to A using intent.it's saying that string object is not initialized @RajenRaiyarela

Comment: @BineeshPBabu when you move back your model.lastAction is null that time that's why it is throwing exception. If you want to avoid that either save the value of that string or change your logic.

Comment: looks like some problem with your code (obvious I know), but you didn't show anything.

Comment: got it. i just wrote code to pass intent using finish() .because i need to pass a value from second activity. thankyou guys.

Answer (score 1):

Just do operation

```
if(lastAction!=null){
//do all stuff here 
}
```

**OR**

pass your object through `onBackPress()` method of `second-activity`.

**OR**

Save your `object` into `sharefrefernce` and get it when `onCreate()` when `Activity` called and `onRestart()` when `activity` will come out from stack.